# Blog vs Blogging tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are currently separate tags for [blog](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) and [blogging](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogging). Since they are both essentially the same thing, should [blogging](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogging) tag be merged into [blog](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) perhaps? Is there any reason these two should be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged the two tags as they really mean the same thing. If you find more possible synonyms report them here and we'll review and if necessary merge them, too.